# How to re-enable Developer Tools on chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

For some reason, the developer tools for Chrome are disabled. I looked up how to fix them, but the answers were for Windows, and I couldn't use them. Can someone tell me how to re-enable developer tools on Chrome?

Comment: Does it work in the [developer version](https://www.google.com/intl/en_in/chrome/dev/) of Chrome? I suppose CTRL + SHIFT + I doesn't work?

Comment: CTR + SHIFT + I doesn't work. The shortcuts do nothing, and the button is greyed out. I haven't tried the developer version yet.

Comment: Looks like it works in the developer version. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent. I thought it might. I'm not sure this *needs* a formal answer written up, but I can (or you can) write one up if you want.